# Can I put a border around an html element that won't be affected by padding/margin?

Tags: html, css

The situation: I have an image that has a 15px padding on the right and I need to put a border or outline around the image. The problem is that both border and outline will be placed on the outer edge of paddings, creating a gap. Is there a method to add a border or outline that will ignore the padding and hug the image itself?

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhk8j/)

HTML:

```
<div class="">
    <img class="" src="http://www.emoticonswallpapers.com/avatar/art/TV-Test-Card.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the browser compatibility on it these days (or if it's even still part of CSS3 or was removed), but a potentially interesting keyword for this is the CSS property `box-sizing`.

Comment: [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) is [well supported](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) and will indeed solve these kind of issues.

Comment: @steveax, if you think `box-sizing` solves the problem, please post your answer, but first check whether it actually works.

Comment: Could you enlighten us as to how you solved this one, please @user1457366, if that IS your real name?

Answer (score 1):

This does it, unless you are trying to cut down on div tags.

```
<div class="outerawesomediv">
  <div class="innerawesomediv">
    <img class="" src="http://www.emoticonswallpapers.com/avatar/art/TV-Test-Card.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

.outerawesomediv
{
 position:relative;
 width:50%;
}
.innerawesomediv
{
 padding-right:15px;
}
img
{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 outline:1px solid #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it:

HTML

```
<div class="some">
    <div class="other">
    <img class="image" src="http://www.emoticonswallpapers.com/avatar/art/TV-Test-Card.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.some {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background:#FEF;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;

    outline: 1px solid #000;
}
.other {
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

That way you will control both separately.

Answer (score 0):

No, because when you use `border` or `outline`, the lines are drawn *by CSS definitions* so that the padding is inside.

So you need to consider replacing padding by something else. There are several possible approaches, and their feasibility depends on the context that was not disclosed in the question. One approach is to use positioning, especially sence you are using it anyway: replace `padding-right: 15px` by the following:

```
left: 0;
right: 15px;
```

Comment: Depending of course upon which `box-sizing` model is active.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that replacing `padding-right` with `margin-right` doesn't affect the border on the image, as shown in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pr95yvze/) JSFiddle.

So the CSS becomes:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px; /*Changed from padding-right*/
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Just leaving this answer here in case anyone in the future needs a quick and easy fix.